# Scrolling of list below another view

Tags: android, user-interface, scroll

I have seen an app which has different type of scrolling. I hope images attached will be able to explain it. Here the list when scrolled up, moves up by taking DownloadAll, Playall button up too. Later on DownloadAll and PlayAll button stops going up and only the list scrolls up.

[image: image1]
[image: image2]
[image: image3]
[image: image4]
[image: image5]

I don't know what this is called as. I tried searching, but could not find anything similar. 
How can I achieve this type of scrolling?

Comment: Check out Material design in android........

Comment: You will get this functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at ["Libraries for developers"](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.desarrollodroide.repos) it has a section of listview where you can find different styles of listviews (plus scrolling animations such as sticky, animated scrollview, flabby etc...)